# Ionic Show Webpage

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Im building an Ionic WebApp and stumbelt over an problem.
I have an webpage with content and i want to use that site as content of an news page on the app. I have been trying and searching for a way to do this for a couple of days now without a acceptable solution.

What I tried:
**Using the ng-include command**
this showed the info but didnt bring the css and made all the links dead.
**Using the in-app-browser plugin**
Just couldnt get it to work.
**Using an Iframe.**
This got the best result but on older android devices(android 2.3) I was unable to scroll.

I have been searching a lot but just couldn't find anything that worked for me.

Good thing to say as well is that my JavaScript knowledge is 0.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For `ng-include` the by default it only renders the safe HTML (by removing all CSS and JS). Try using  `getTrustedResourceUrl(value);`for marking resource as safe (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce).

Also (assuming that you are making a mobile app) if iframe is not working on older Android you can use [croswalk](http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/?utm_content=buffer6c04c&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer).

Hope this helps !! :)

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I however ended up using rss feeds to display it which worked like a charm.